# jQuery Event-Handler changes CSS-Class with a shift of one click

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I have some kind of strange behaviour using jQuery's Click-Function. I also tried it with the on-EventHandler. There is some simple markup from Twitter's Bootstrap Navbar and I'm trying to change the CSS-Class of an li-tag. In this case I want to remove the CSS-Class active and add it to the currently clicked li-tag. But the change get's applied with a shift of one click. So when when e.g. 'Preview' is the current visual active element and I click on 'Document', the CSS-Class seems not to be changed. When I click afterwards on 'Slidecast', then the visual active element is 'Document' which is not the expected behavoiur. Next Click on 'Preview' and now 'Slidecast' is the visual active element. What I'm doing wrong? I tried it with remove and add and also with toggleClass, but that doesen't matter. Here is my code and markup. JS is wrapped into a Dom-Ready-Function.

```
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#!document_defaultview">Document</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!document_slidecast">Slidecast</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!document_preview">Preview</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!document_notes">Notes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!document_questions">Questions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#!document_activities">Activities</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$("#document_navbar a").on('click', function(e) {

    // Hide all content, display the one related to hash-tag    
    $(".document_view").toggle(false);
    $(app_locationToId($(this).attr("href"))).toggle(true);


    // Here is the part that does not work:     
    //$("#document_navbar li.active").removeClass("active");
    //$("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").parent().addClass('active');

            // Another try ... same result as described above!  
    $("#document_navbar li.active").toggleClass("active", false);
    $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").parent().toggleClass("active", true);
});
```

OK according to your answers, here is the code I've used to handle that problem:

```
$("#document_navbar a").on('click', function(e) {

    new_location = app_locationToId($(this).attr("href"));

    // Hide all content, display the one related to hash-tag    
    $(".document_view").toggle(false);
    $(new_location).toggle(true);
    // Change visual active li-tag
    $("#document_navbar li.active").toggleClass("active", false);
    $("a[href='" + app_IdToLocation(new_location) + "']").parent().toggleClass("active", true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the hashchange event on the window object in order to add your 'active' class:

```
$(".navbar li a").on('click', function(e) {
    // Hide all content, display the one related to hash-tag    
    $(".document_view").toggle(false);    
    $('.navbar li').removeClass("active", false);
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").parent().addClass("active", true);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4fEE/)

Comment: Ooooo... I like this approach. :)

Comment: Yes also a nice approach to seperate these concerns!

Answer (score 0):

When click function is triggered the `window.location.hash` is the one of the actual page. So you must be sure that the hash is changed and then take it and toggle class.

Searching for a code snippet on my stuff and edit/post it for you soon. :)

Edit:

So here you are, it's a snippet of one of my older projects before I started using history.js class:

```
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var hashListener = null, hashValue = '', hashQuery;

    function checkIfHashChanged() {
        var hashQuery = window.location.hash;
        if (hashQuery === hashValue) { return; }
        hashValue = hashQuery;

        //Do the toggle
        $("#document_navbar li.active").toggleClass("active", false);
        $("a[href='" + hashQuery + "']").parent().toggleClass("active", true);
    }

    function startHashListener() {
        setInterval(checkIfHashChanged, 100);
    }

    function stopHashListener() {
        if (hashListener !== null) { clearInterval(hashListener); }
        hashListener = null;
    }

    startHashListener();

});
```

This code runs outside of your click function and just listens for a hashchange during interval hashlistener.

Comment: Thanks for this snippet! It's a little bit too complex for my simple requirement, but I will recap your statement about using something that takes care of all the history-stuff. Nice suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that `window.location.hash` gets updated after the click handler is done. As a result, you will always get the "old" location in your click handler.  Afterwards the location gets updated, but you won't be using it until the next click... therefore you are always one click off.

To test this, I would put a short delay on the execution of the class toggle:

```
$("#document_navbar a").on('click', function(e) {

    // Hide all content, display the one related to hash-tag    
    $(".document_view").toggle(false);
    $(app_locationToId($(this).attr("href"))).toggle(true);

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#document_navbar li.active").toggleClass("active", false);
        $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").parent().toggleClass("active", true);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Doing some fast repeating clicks should kill this solution I suggest, but we cant test it actually. Another problem will be, that you can't use crosslinks e.g. outside of a text element on page without binding another click handler.

Comment: First off, this was not necessarily meant as a "solution", and more as a demonstration of where the problem originates. Secondly, several fast repeating clicks should still work. They just trigger several timeouts.  The last timeout will still do the correct thing.  Lastly, I have no idea what you mean with your second sentence.

Comment: I am sorry didn't want to be offending. I ment when calling e.g. <a href="#!document_notes">Notes</a></li> not from navbar, instead from a text link the toggle would not be called.

Comment: You were not offending... :)  Just wanted to clarify my answer. You are absolutely right, clicks on links outside of `#document_navbar a` would not update correctly.  But that was already a flaw in the OPs original code.  But it's certainly worth pointing that out, though.

Comment: Yes of course, this makes sense! I didn't caught that! Thanks for all solutions, each of them is a nice way to handle this! I'm going to update my question with the solultion I have applied.