# Toggle menu active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

Hey I am doing a menu and I want that when I click the item enter in active position and then when another item is clicked it changes to the recently clicked to active and remove the state from the last one, this is what I am doing but is not working... I appreciate if someone can help me.

HTML

```
<div id="nav-pPal">
  <ul class="nav-Ppal">
    <li><a class="btns-nav" id="0" href="#block-intro">01</a></li>
    <li><a class="btns-nav" id="1" href="#block-pq-zolfunza">02</a></li>
    <li><a class="btns-nav" id="2" href="#block-modulos-zolfunza">03</a></li>
    <li><a class="btns-nav" id="3" href="#block-seguridad">04</a></li>
    <li><a class="btns-nav" id="4" href="#block-desarrollo">05</a></li>
    <li><a class="btns-nav" id="5" href="#block-nuestra-ubic">06</a></li>
    <li><a class="btns-nav" id="6" href="#block-noticias">07</a></li>
    <li><a class="btns-nav" id="7" href="#block-preguntas">08</a></li>
    <li><a class="btns-nav" id="8" href="#block-contacto">09</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-Ppal li a {
width: 30px;
height: 22px;
padding-top:8px;
text-align:center;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
cursor:pointer;
background-color: #000;
color: #FFF;
opacity: 1;
-moz-opacity: 0.70;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=70);
cursor:pointer;
font-family: 'lucida_sans_unicoderegular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
}
.nav-Ppal li a:hover {
background-color: #f7941e;
color: #FFF;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
cursor:pointer;
}

.nav-Ppal-active{
background: white;
color: black;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".nav-Ppal li a").on("click", checkTarget);
function checkTarget(){
    /*$(".nav-Ppal li a").not(this).removeClass(".nav-Ppal_active");*/
    $(".nav-Ppal li a").addClass("nav-Ppal-active");
    console.log("click");
}
```

Comment: why are you doing it that way?

Comment: FYI: You should never start an `id` attribute with a number, much less have the whole attribute be completely numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function() {
 $(".nav-Ppal li a").on("click", function() {
    $(".nav-Ppal li a").removeClass('nav-Ppal-active');
    $(this).addClass("nav-Ppal-active");
  });
});
```

This is what you want to do

Change your CSS:

```
.nav-Ppal-active{
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

Your specificity is being overridden by your default class.

Working link: http://jsfiddle.net/barrychapman/epaE3/3/

Comment: Don't forget to remove the console.log after you've verified the function works. It will break some browsers.

Comment: More specifically, it will break IE9. In case you want to leave the debug functionality, just replace console.log() with an empty dummy function. When you return to working on your code, you won't have to reinsert dozens on console.log() statements everywhere.

Comment: i dont know why is not working for me, im using a script to do scroll parallax so i dont know if that is what is not letting me do this thing with the menu

Comment: The console log doesnt output any error thats why im not sure why is not working the addClass on jquery, but when i ad css in this way it works.

    $(".nav-Ppal li a").on("click", function() {
        $(this).css({
         background: "white",
         color: "black"
         });
     });

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barrychapman/epaE3/3/ the problem is your CSS specificity

Comment: :( dont understand what sould be the problem :/ just got it in this way...

  `  $(".nav-Ppal li a").on("click", function() {
     $(".nav-Ppal li a").css({
      background: "#000",
      color: "#fff"
     });
        $(this).css({
         background: "white",
         color: "black"
         });
     }); `

Comment: You aren't listening to me! Fix your CSS selector in your stylesheet to be more specific for the active class!

Comment: you were right....it just needed to be more specific, im now having a problem that is not adding the class the first time you click on the men, but then the other times it just work really good...ill see if i can figure it our what is it

Comment: nevermind i just called my function inside another called the same lol im really good right now, thank you for your help! i appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to a [solution I recently came up with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623126/jquery-event-handler-changes-css-class-with-a-shift-of-one-click/15623324#15623324) that uses the "hashchange" browser event to set the active element.

Here's a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/h4fEE/1/) that you can use.

Javascript:

```
$(".nav-Ppal li a").on('click', function(e) {
    // Hide all content, display the one related to hash-tag    
    $(".document_view").toggle(false);    
    $('.nav-Ppal li').removeClass("nav-Ppal-active", false);
});

$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").parent().addClass("nav-Ppal-active", true);
});
```

Also, put the "active" class on your first element so that something looks active when it first loads:

```
<li class="nav-Ppal-active">
```